# If a data extract is perfomed via api will it be displayed in automation studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, data-extract

I want to trigger a data extract activity in marketing cloud using SOAP api but i don't want that activity to be visible under automation studio activities(suppose i'm an ISV, I dont want my client to know which all data i will be pulling specfically so that he gets to know more about my algorithm).Is there any way to achieve this.Will a new automation shows up if i perform a data extract using soap as mentioned in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api.htm

Comment: Why would you want the extract not to show in the first place?

Comment: suppose i'm an ISV, I dont want my client to know which all data i will be pulling specfically so that he gets to know more about my algorithm..i have edited the question to include this info too